# How to draw a responsive 'T' shape in HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am working on a project which requires drawing something akin to a letter 'T' in HTML and making it responsive.

```
--------IMG-------------------------------------
         |
         |
         |
```

I have an image right at the junction point.
I would like the whole thing to be responsive.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the code because the diagram details are proprietary.

But the issue that I face is the following:

1. When I resize the window, the vertical line moves at a different speed than the horizontal line and hence the vertical line is no longer under image.

What kind of strategy should I follow in my CSS and HTML to ensure that this is responsive?

I am very new to HTML and having basic knowledge of making images responsive and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: You might not be able to share the code for IP reasons but you could create a [mcve] for us to troubleshoot the issue faster

Comment: Use a grid system, any grid system, and make each container 50%, then add a border (or outline to not take up any layout) to one of those containers and voila. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use this code on your img it will make it responsive

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

That will ensure your image scales as your browser shrinks.

To get the line to stay in the same position make sure it's within the same container as the image. You could then just adjust the margin of the line.

Below is a fiddle of this.

https://jsfiddle.net/15fmcs5e/

As you will notice as your resize the browser the line stays in place as the image shrinks. When the display starts getting to small the line stops moving over. At this point you would need to use a media query to adjust how far over you want the margin on the line.

That could look something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/L1bbfxdq/1/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 836px) {
   .line {
     margin-left:60px;
  }
}
```

You could also just make the .line class have a percentage based margin from the get go and save yourself doing the media query. Whatever works best for you.